# LWC: how to let users use file uploads in design attributes section

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how Salesforce does some styling around the design attributes of LWCs. Mostly I am interested in how to allow users to upload a file in the design attribute.

I was able to create something using apex that shows a picklist with all the assets that meet a criteria, but I'm looking for a little more and I don't see in the documentation anything about doing sophisticated things in the js-meta.xml files.

It seems like one of those things that should be a pre-built package, but I didn't see a way to implement it in the LWC library

[I've recorded a Loom to explain exactly what I'm trying to figure out.] (https://www.loom.com/share/ee8c7306cd85496eaa6d7aa66292b941)

Thanks in advance for any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are not yet possible with custom components. The standard components have extra functionality, but we do not know when, or if, such features might be available to us in the future. For now, you can only use the features described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags).

Comment: Note to future visitors: Please feel free to comment or edit this answer when such features are available.